# Ansible: how to replace text in string with items

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible command which returns me a list of directories:

```
- local_action: command find {{ role_path }}/files -type f
  register: result
```

It returned, for example, two paths: `path/files/a/1.zip` and `path/files/a/2.zip`. I need to cut the start of the string path/files, leave `/a/1.zip` and `/a/2.zip` and register the result for deleting these files. I tried `regex_replace` and shell with `sed`. But this did not work. Is it possible to do?

```
  - command: "echo {{item}} | sed s/'{{ role_path }}/files'/''"
    with_items: "{{result.stdout_lines}}"
    register: script_results

  - msg: {{ item | regex_replace('/path/files','\\1') }}
    with_items: "{{result.stdout_lines}}"
```

Comment: How about using [find](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/find_module.html) module instead of dancing with shell commands?

Comment: You can't use shell features like `|` in a `command` task.  You need to use a `shell` task.

Comment: I wanted to use ansible find but I could run it locally only on client side. And I need find file which are stored in role. So find in shell command works fine for me.

Comment: @larsks When I use this shell: ${{{item}}#{{ role_path }}/files/} I get error -
 template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'. When I use this shell: echo {{item}} | sed 's/{{ role_path }}/files/ ' I get error - sed: -e expression #1, char 162: unterminated `s' command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments: you should not use commands in the first place. You can delegate the [`find`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/find_module.html) task to `127.0.0.1` and it should execute in the machine where you execute the playbook.

You can use [the `relpath` filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html) to remove the start of paths and you can use the `map` filter with `attribute` to conveniently extract the path:

```
- find:
    path: "{{ role_path }}"
    recurse: yes
  register: result
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

- debug:
    msg: "{{ item | relpath(role_path) }}"
  with_items: "{{ result.files | map(attribute='path')}}"
```

The output you will get will be something like the example below. The values don't start with slash, but I think that you can easily fix this.

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=/path/to/role/dir/file_1) => {
    "item": "/path/to/role/dir/file_1", 
    "msg": "dir/file_1"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea with relpath. But I confused a little bit about to make this {{ item | relpath(role_path + '/files') }} in debug section. Is it right? Does ansible have a special section for this operation?

Comment: @Risha: this is called [a filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#id27) and the meaning of it is that what is on the left side is passed as an input to the filter. The filter itself also can have parameters as `role_path` in this case. Eventually the parametrized filter processes the input to get an output. In this case the result is a relative path from the path passed as the parameter to the path passed as the input.